# Passivbildung bei transitiven und intransitiven Verben

Tags: grammar

in meinem Grammatikbuch steht, dass transitive Verben (=Verben mit Akkusativobjekt: ich gieße die Blumen) den Passiv bilden können (die Blumen werden gegossen), während intransitive Verben (=Verben mit Dativ- oder Genitivobjekt: Ich helfe ihm), den Passiv nicht bilden können.

Das finde ich merkwürdig, weil ich doch den Passiv von "Ich helfe ihm" bilden kann: Ihm wird geholfen.

Was ist hier mein Denkfehler?

Danke im Voraus

Comment: Was sagt die Grammatik denn wörtlich? Ich glaube zum Beispiel schon nicht, daß sie „intransitive Verben = Verben mit Dativ- oder Genitivobjekt“ sagt.

Comment: Im Grammatikbuch von Pons (2013) "Grammatik kurz&bündig - Deutsch als Fremdsprache" steht wortwörtlich auf Seite 81: "Transitive Verben haben ein Akkusativobjekt: Sie mag ihn. Intransitive Verben ein Dativ-, Genitiv-, Präpositional- oder gar kein Objekt: Er hilft ihr".

Comment: Genau, *Präpositional- oder gar kein Objekt*. :-)

Comment: »Sie werden geholfen«? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich kenne die Formulierung in deinem Grammatikbuch nicht, aber bei [Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Valenz/Trans-Intrans.html) steht zum Beispiel:

> „Echte“ transitive Verben können ins Vorgangspassiv (werden-Passiv) gesetzt werden, wobei das Akkusativobjekt zum Subjekt wird.

Dagegen:

> Intransitive Verben bilden entweder ein subjektloses Vorgangspassiv oder gar kein Vorgangspassiv.

Das Beispiel ist genau "ihm wird geholfen": Es gibt kein Subjekt (man kann ein unpersönliches "es" einfügen, wenn man will) und das Dativobjekt bleibt Dativobjekt.

Also ist entweder das, was in deinem Grammatikbuch steht, falsch, oder du hast die Formulierung dort falsch verstanden.

Einige Details darüber, welche intransitive Verben ein subjektloses Passiv bilden und welche nicht, gibt es [hier](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Genera/NoPassiv1.html#Anchor-Intransitive-23240).

Comment: Danke für die Antwort; intransitive Verben können also ein Passiv bilden. Ich habe das Gefühl, dass das Grammatikbuch, da es sich nicht an deutsche Muttersprachler richtet, den Sachverhalt so vereinfacht, dass es am Ende falsch ist. Denn wie kann man den folgenden wortwörtlich zitierten Satz sonst verstehen: "Transitive Verben können das Passiv bilden. Ein intransitives Verb kann kein Passiv bilden." (Seite 64, Grammatik kurz&bündig, Pons)

Comment: @WebDevJunior: Ja, möglicherweise ist es zu stark vereinfacht. In der "großen Grammatik" von Pons (https://books.google.de/books?id=GI4K3hWv9nAC&pg=PA244&lpg=PA244&dq=intransitiv+pons+grammatik+deutsch&source=bl&ots=IDR-PpqipI&sig=c0Z5ddsjP03cChM_V91miHCdlcI&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmlo6E1urLAhVBqw4KHcBkAk0Q6AEIFDAA) steht es richtig.